# Newly generated ASP.NET Core 3.1 app won't run due to Startup.Configure NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've just created a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API, and this is my first time running it. I've added some endpoints and starting code and altered the Startup with some extra configurations, but the program isn't running at all. I'm not sure whether my startup is affecting this but I can't see any anything I've added would break the startup sequence.

The exception I'm getting is:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at -snip-.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\-snip-\Startup.cs:line 56
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at -snip-.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\-snip-\Program.cs:line 16
```

Startup class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "",
                    Version = "v1"
                });
            });

            services.AddTransient<IClientSettingsBlobService, ClientSettingsBlobService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            
            string origins = Configuration["CorsAllowedOrigins"];
            string[] originsArray = origins.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(o => o.Trim()).ToArray();
            app.UseCors(b => b.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().WithOrigins(originsArray));
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
    }
```

Comment: here `string origins = Configuration["CorsAllowedOrigins"];`  ... if `origins` is null, then `Split` will cause a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Try debugging `Configure`(you can do it, just place a breakpoint). I would say that `string origins = Configuration["CorsAllowedOrigins"];` sets `origins` to `null`.

Comment: @LegacyCode Glossed over that completely. Works perfect now, thanks. If you want to post an answer below I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: P.S.: There is a line number in the exception `Startup.cs:line 56`. So you should be able to find the problematic line that you should inspect via debugger without guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `string origins = Configuration["CorsAllowedOrigins"];` ... if `origins` is null, then `Split` will cause a `NullReferenceException`